# SPA, website using oauth2 api - do I need csrf protection

Tags: javascript, php, security, web, single-page-application

My website is full SPA, and all of the authenticated user's requests are done using access token, the only form that unauthenticated users have access to is login form. So is csrf protection necessary? What potential security issues could I face if I disable csrf protection from my website? Thanks.

Comment: how is the access token sent to the client? How does the client send it back?

Comment: As a response to post request, then attached to header as bearer token. PS I did set up SSL to protect the traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your setup, it is as follows:

1. User POSTs credentials (eg: login form)
2. Server returns auth token in response
3. User includes token in a request header with every subsequent request

If this is accurate, and assuming that you're using TLS and properly validating tokens, I think you are already well protected against Cross-Site-Request-Forgeries.

The typical CSRF protection is to send a token that only the legitimate website can see (eg, by setting a cookie), and then expecting that same token to be returned either in follow-up request headers, query parameters (not a good idea), or request body. Token-based authentication such as yours already meets these requirements.

In short, if an evil site is able to circumvent your setup to forge requests (CSRF), then the evil site could probably use the same vulnerability to defeat a typical CSRF protection.